# How can I format a number with leading zeros and thousands commas?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an int field in a MySQL database that is progressively going up every time a user of the database performs a specific action so it's going up in increments of 1.

When displaying this on a php page, I want it to display this value as `0,000,001` rather than it's raw data of just `1`.

How do I format the number to display like this? I've never had to do it before, so I'm bewildered.

Comment: Convert it to a string and pad the beginning with however many 0s and commas you need.

Comment: A more specific title. Trim the question down to just the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT INSERT(INSERT(LPAD([value], 7, '0'), 5, 0, ','), 2, 0, ',')
FROM ....
```

`LPAD` returns a string of length 7, with leading 0's. If [value] is longer than 7 it will be truncated (from the right); so '12345678' becomes '1234567'.

The two `INSERT` calls insert the commas.

Edit: Changed the 1's to 0's; apparently they effectively made it a "replace" rather than an "insert".

I'd suggest doing this in code though, instead of a query, if you can.

Comment: Will this remove 0's as the actual data gets bigger or will it always keep the same amount of 0's in front of the original number?

Comment: @Equinox04 The final string's length remains constant; I added some explanation above the 'Edit', but below the query fragment. If you're worried about going to "100 million", you'll probably need some `IF()`'s or `CASE`'s to adjust comma positions for longer strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you would rather do it in the php, something like:

```
$pretty = substr(number_format(10000000 + $counter), 1);
```

this will work as long as counter never exceeds 9,999,999.